# Populating dropdown list from database in mvc partial page

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm trying to populate data in the dropdown list at partial page and calling it in layout page. I'm getting null reference error. I tried to do it using a view and could populate the data in the drop down list but when I try it in the partial view and then call it in the layout page then I get the error the error is on the partial page view code   @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SiteId, Model.SiteNames)

Error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Controller

```
 public List<SelectListItem> GetPopulateDropDown()
        {


            List<SelectListItem> names = _db.Sites.Select(n => new SelectListItem { Text = n.SiteId.ToString(), Value = n.Name }).ToList();

            return names;

        }

        public ActionResult PopulateDropDown()
        {



            var DashboardList = GetPopulateDropDown();

            var dropdownData = DashboardList
                .Select(d => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = d.Text, //Need to apply the correct text field here
                    Value = d.Value //Need to apply the correct value field here
                })
                .ToList();
            dropdownData.Add(new SelectListItem { Text= "a", Value="1"});
            var model = new SiteListViewModel
            {
                SiteNames = dropdownData
            };



                return PartialView(model);



        }
```

PartialView

```
@model MeterPortal.ViewModels.PremiseMeter.SiteListViewModel




    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SiteId, Model.SiteNames)
```

Model

```
        public int SiteId { get; set; }
        public string SiteName { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SiteNames { get; set; }
```

Comment: Where abouts in the code above do you get the error???

Comment: @JamesS in the partial view code where I placed the dropdown.

Comment: Before you call the view with that dropdown list in, is it even populated as the error would suggest that `Model.SiteNames` isn't populated Also a dropdownlistFor should be coded such as `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SiteId, new SelectList(Model.SiteNames, "id", "value"))`

Comment: In the second last line of controller I added data to the model's list which should not let it be null. I also added a line of static content to it to make it anything but null. @JamesS

Comment: @JamesS Tried changing the view code but got same error.

Comment: @wizwind how are you trying to render the `PartialView` from the parent `View`? Also, is it possible to use `RenderPartial` from your parent page and then its quite easy to populate the `SiteNames` dropdown enumerable with some razor in your `PartialView`

Comment: @AbdulG I actually had parialview instead of view and I passed it like return PartialView("Layout", model); but when nothing seemed to work I just posted it in here.

Comment: Please show the view in which contains your partial view.